# Maven dependency commanted jars are generated in war file

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to generate the war file , war generated successfully but when i decompress and check the jars inside lib , the commented Maven dependencies also appears on it.

How to resolve this issue

Ex:

```
<!--  
<dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernatecore </artifactId> <version>5.6.8.Final</version> </dependency>
-->
```

This commented hibernate jar appears in war.

I tried mvn clean , clean install, -X clean install , package also run maven upadte with force no results found
Can any one help me please

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the target folder before clean install? Also is it possible that one of your other dependencies is pulling hibernatecore?

Comment: Not an answer, but shouldn't that final `>` actually be `-->` instead, to close the commented section? Does the text in the question accurately reflect the contents of the POM? If so, why does the POM contain `===...`?

Comment: @andrewJames is right, the comment should be closed using -->

Comment: It could be an indirect dependency meaning other dependency in your pom might be dependent on it. Pls chek it or post the pom.xml details here

Comment: I checked the dependency:tree i didn't find any hibernate on tree

Comment: TLDR transitive dependencies.

Comment: Show your full pom file...